# Is there a layered architecture diagram for Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, whisper, architecture, documentation

I wonder if there is a layered architecture diagram for Ethereum that shows from the lowest level to the highest level like the one of Java (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/index.html)?

It could be very useful indeed.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Ethereum Web Stack]

Not so detailed as per the Java documentation, but this figure is floating around the internet which is quite apt to begin with, in order to fill in further details.

Ref: https://www.easyeth.com/components-of-ethereum-part-1.html

Comment: If the figure is floating around the Internet, you should include a citation to give credit to its author.